# string.format(): multiline string without using plus

Tags: c#

how string.format() can help to avoid using "+" in such statement:

```
 
string statement =" SELECT DISTINCT titel as linieName" +
                  " FROM qry_Forecast_Taktzeiten" +
                  " WHERE linieName LIKE 'lin%';";
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to achive. What do you want to replace using string format?

Comment: I hope this SQL query is only for the purpose of the question and that you would never do this in a real program as it could be subject to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: The query in it self, i.e. as it is stated above, is save as there is no variable part in it. The chance of an sql injection only occurs if any part of the query is made variable, and the variable is filled by a string replacement and not by the use of a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement above the `+` is used to concatenate seveal strings you created to make your code more readable. `String.Format` will not help you here!

To avoid the string concatenation you could do the following:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(" SELECT DISTINCT titel as linieName");
sb.Append(" FROM qry_Forecast_Taktzeiten");
sb.Append(" WHERE linieName LIKE 'lin%';");
statement = sb.ToString();
```

If you want to replace the 'lin' with some variable you have you can use:

```
string statement =" SELECT DISTINCT titel as linieName" +
                  " FROM qry_Forecast_Taktzeiten" +
                  " WHERE linieName LIKE '{0}';";
statement = string.Format(staement, "lin%");
```

or

```
sb.AppendFormat(" WHERE linieName LIKE '{0}';", "lin%");
```

However, all of the methods above using string replacement ({0}) bear the risk of an **SQL injection attack** if the  "lin%" is obtained from a user entry.

So the best bet is to use:

```
string statement =" SELECT DISTINCT titel as linieName" +
                      " FROM qry_Forecast_Taktzeiten" +
                      " WHERE linieName LIKE @match;";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = statement;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@match", "lin%"));
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to avoid the plus operators here - the compiler joins string constants at compile time, hence the concatenation will not occur at runtime.

Comment: Also, up to I believe 5 concats, a concat is much faster than a string.Format. I personally avoid overdoing this string.Format stuff, specially in very simple concatinations with a single variable or so.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `@` operator

```
String linebreaks = @"Break
                      Lines
                      With @";
```

As Daniel Brückner points out, the contents of `linebreaks` will contain spaces. Here's what the output of the above code will look like:

```
"Break
                       Lines
                       With @"
```

This is not an issue if you are storing SQL.

Comment: Just to note, this will add line breaks after each line and is not the same as "Break" + "Lines" + "With @". And it will include all the leading whitespace of each line, too. So the result is something like "Breaks\r\n     Lines\r\n      With @" assuming Environment.NewLine is '\r\n'.

Comment: Updated my answer, Daniel. English is not my native tongue; so feel free to update it if I'm not making myself clear :)

Answer (score 2):

It won't in this case, because the **+** is simply there to break your statement across multiple lines. You would use string.Format() when you want to substitute values into the string, like this:

```
string statement = string.Format("SELECT DISTINCT title FROM table WHERE title LIKE '{0}%'", MyTextBox.Text);
```

This is just an example. PLEASE NEVER NEVER NEVER do this - it leads to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

string statement = @"SELECT DISTINCT titel as linieName
                     FROM qry_Forecast_Taktzeiten
                     WHERE linieName LIKE 'lin%';";